# Update List Value SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table.

```
ID   | VALUE
id_1 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
id_2 | 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
id_3 | 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

And I need change value by value += 1, eventually the table should look like:

```
ID   | VALUE
id_1 | 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
id_2 | 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
id_3 | 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
```

How can I do that? Is it possible do it with SQL query? And what type I should set for `VALUE`, numeric or text?

Comment: It is possible, but it is extremely hard. Problems like this are perfect illustration of why you don’t want to store lists in string properties.

Answer (score 1):

As another user noted, relational databases work best with single values stored in columns. That said, you *can* parse the value (split by delimiter), increment the numbers, join them to a string and update the row. You would need to create a custom procedure for that. See [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) and [stored routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines.html).

If you *must* do that, you should declare the column as TEXT or VARCHAR; the list like you showed above cannot be stored in to a numeric column.

A full answer is question of some heavy SQL programming. Also even if you come up with a working solution, the risk that your program works only on one database is considerable.

So:

Much easier way is to store the two-dimensional data by separate ids for row and position:

```
id   | pos | value
------------------
id_1 | 1   | 1
id_1 | 2   | 2
id_1 | 3   | 3
...
id_2 | 1   | 6
...
```

If there are other fields besides the number list for a specific id, make another table like the one above, where `id` is a foreign key in the main table.

Then updating values is simply matter of issuing

```
UPDATE table_name SET value = value + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with Python script:

```js
db = sqlite3.connect('Database.db')

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT Value FROM Problems')

all_rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in all_rows:
    array = row[0].split(',')
    new_string = ''
    for id in array:
        if (id != ''):
            id = int(id)
            id += 1
            id = str(id)
            new_string += id + ','
    new_string = new_string[:-1]
    cursor.execute('UPDATE Problems SET Value = ? WHERE Value = ?', (new_string, row[0]))
    db.commit()
db.close
```

Answer (score 1):

The UPDATE below works:

```
create table t as
  select 'id_1' id, '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'      val union
  select 'id_2' id, '6, 7, 8, 9, 10'     val union
  select 'id_3' id, '11, 12, 13, 14, 15' val;

update t set val=(
  with
  cnt(x) as (select 1 union all select x+1 from cnt limit 999),
  split  as (select id, x from t,cnt where instr(' '||val||',', ' '||x||',')>0)
  select group_concat(x+1,', ') val from split where id=t.id
);

select * from t order by id;
```

Result:

```
id_1|2, 3, 4, 5, 6
id_2|7, 8, 9, 10, 11
id_3|12, 13, 14, 15, 16
```

It works if your values are integers between 1 and the given limit, set to 999 in this example. I tested this successfully on Sqlite version 3.11.